# How to load multiple scripts dynamically in specific order?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to load x scripts (let's say 6 for this example) dynamically (either in TypeScript and JavaScript) .

The first 2 scripts are used by the last 4.  So I have to ensure that script 1 and 2 have loaded prior to loading the last 4.

```
var scripts = [
  { "path": "f1.js", "isDependency": true },
  { "path": "f2.js", "isDependency": true },
  { "path": "f3.js", "isDependency": false },
  { "path": "f4.js", "isDependency": false },
  { "path": "f5.js", "isDependency": false },
  { "path": "f6.js", "isDependency": false }
];
```

And I have an async function that loads scripts, but I am having trouble setting up async/await or promises that wait for first 2 scripts to load and then let the others load in whatever order.

```
private async loadJsFileAsync(filePath: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!document.getElementById(filePath)) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');

      script.onload = function () {
        // mark with attribute so we know that it's loaded
        script.attributes["data-loaded"] = "true";
        resolve();
      }
      script.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      }

      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = filePath
      script.id = filePath;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    } else {
      // file processed, but check to see it actually loaded
      var s1 = <HTMLScriptElement>document.getElementById(filePath);
      var loadedAttribute = s1.attributes["data-loaded"] === "true";
      if (loadedAttribute) {
        resolve();
      } else {

        // add event listeners (in addition to the existing ones)
        s1.addEventListener("load", function () {
          resolve();
        });
        s1.addEventListener("error", function (err) {
          reject(err);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

At the moment I using the async function with only a single required script in the following manner:

```
this.loadJsFileAsync("f1.js").then(value => {

  // load other files
  loadJsFile("f3.js");
  loadJsFile("f4.js");
  loadJsFile("f5.js");
  loadJsFile("f6.js");
});

private loadJsFile(filePath: string) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = filePath + this.version();
  script.id = filePath;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your usage of the function? (How you're using await)

Comment: @mwilson Right now I just use the function with a single required scripts.  Posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First and foremost, why not use requirejs or some other module loader? They provide you the ability to chain your scripts so dependencies are loaded first. Secondly, I think this is what you want:

There's definitely room for improvement and optimization here, but it should give you the result you're looking for.

```
class Script {
    constructor(path, dependencyOrder) {
        this.path = path;
        this.dependencyOrder = dependencyOrder;
    }
}
class ScriptLoader {
    constructor() {
        this.scripts = [];

    }
    addScript(script) {
        const exists = this.scripts.find( s => s.path.toLowerCase() === script.path.toLowerCase());
        if (!exists) {
            this.scripts.push(script);
        }
    }
    async loadScripts() {
        if (Array.isArray(this.scripts)) {
            const orderedScripts = this.orderScriptsByDependency();
            let scriptsLoaded = false;
            let counter = 0;
            while (!scriptsLoaded) {
                const _script = orderedScripts[counter]
                await this.loadScript(_script, _script.dependencyOrder > -1);
                counter += 1;
                scriptsLoaded = counter === orderedScripts.length;
            }
        }
    }
    async loadScript(script, waitToLoad) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
            scriptTag.src = script.path;
            if (waitToLoad) {
                scriptTag.async = true;
                document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
                scriptTag.onload = () => { resolve(); }
            } else {
                document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
                resolve();
            }
        } );
    }
    orderScriptsByDependency() {
        if (Array.isArray(this.scripts)) {
            return this.scripts.sort( (a, b) => {
                return a.dependencyOrder - b.dependencyOrder;
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class IndexView {
    constructor() {
        this.loader = new ScriptLoader();
        this.init();
    }
    async init() {
        this.loader.addScript(new Script('scripts/script0.js', 0));
        this.loader.addScript(new Script('scripts/script1.js', 1));
        this.loader.addScript(new Script('scripts/script2.js', 2));
        await this.loader.loadScripts();
    }
}
```

[Requirejs](https://requirejs.org/)

Comment: oops. Forgot to return the value in my sort function. Updating now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve order, you can utilize `onload` of `HtmlScriptElement` like this.

```
const loadScripts = (urls: string[]): void => {
  urls.forEach((url, index) => {
    const js = loadScript(url);
    if (index < urls.length) {
      js.onload = () => {
        loadScript(urls[index + 1]);
      };
    }
  });
};

const loadScript = (url: string): HTMLScriptElement => {
  const js = document.createElement("script");
  js.setAttribute("src", url);
  document.body.appendChild(js);
  return js;
};
```

And call it like this:

```
loadScripts(["script1.js", "script2.js", "script3.js"]);
```

Comment: This would load each individual script one at a time. That's a long load time if you've got a lot of scripts...

Comment: Yes - your solution is better with asynchronous loading.

Comment: @mwilson I have added an answer with a jQuery function which loads scripts without chaining it.